React useState popup is opening, but I can't close it
I am following a beginner tutorial for an ecommerce website and while making the Sign in popup, I made a component for it and mounted it on the navbar component. It will open the popup when you click on the sign in button.
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Navbar.css'
import { assets } from '../../assets/assets'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = ({setShowLogin}) => {

  const [menu, setMenu] = useState("home");

  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
      <img src={assets.logo} alt="" className='logo' />
      <ul className="navbar-menu">
        <Link to='/' onClick={()=>setMenu("home")} className {menu==="home"?"active":""}>home</Link>
        <a href='#explore-menu' onClick={()=>setMenu("menu")} className={menu==="menu"?"active":""}>menu</a>
        <a href='#app-download' onClick={()=>setMenu("mobile-app")} className={menu==="mobile-app"?"active":""}>mobile-app</a>
        <a href='#footer' onClick={()=>setMenu("contact-us")} className={menu==="contact-us"?"active":""}>contact us</a>
        <div className="navbar-right">
          <img src={assets.search_icon} alt="" />
          <div className="navbar-search-icon">
            <img src={assets.basket_icon} alt="" />
            <div className="dot"></div>
          </div>
          <button onClick={()=>setShowLogin(true)}>sign in</button>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar

Here I am using the useState hook to make the showLogin and setShowLogin functionalities inside App.jsx and initializing it as false. I then pass the props to the Navbar.
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home/Home";
import Cart from "./pages/Cart/Cart";
import PlaceOrder from "./pages/PlaceOrder/PlaceOrder";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import LoginPopup from "./components/LoginPopup/LoginPopup";

const App = () => {

  const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
    {showLogin?<LoginPopup setShowLogin={setShowLogin} />:<></>}
      <div className="app">
        <Navbar setShowLogin={setShowLogin} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
          <Route path="/order" element={<PlaceOrder />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;

Then, I added an image inside the popup component for the purpose of closing the popup. But even when I set it to false it won't close.
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './LoginPopup.css'
import { assets } from '../../assets/assets';

const LoginPopup = (setShowLogin) => {

    const [currState, setCurrState] = useState("Sign Up");

  return (
    <div className='login-popup'>
        <form className="login-popup-container">
            <div className="login-popup-title">
                <h2>{currState}</h2>
                <img onClick={()=>setShowLogin(false)} src={assets.cross_icon} alt="" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginPopup

Haven't really completed all of it, but in the tutorial the guy is able to close it right after coding it and I double checked to see if I missed something. What am I doing wrong?

You are not receiving the prop correctly, you need to destructure setShowLogin like this:
const LoginPopup = ({setShowLogin}) => {

    const [currState, setCurrState] = useState("Sign Up");

  return (
    <div className='login-popup'>
        <form className="login-popup-container">
            <div className="login-popup-title">
                <h2>{currState}</h2>
                <img onClick={()=>setShowLogin(false)} src={assets.cross_icon} alt="" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

Or like this:
const LoginPopup = (props) => {

    const [currState, setCurrState] = useState("Sign Up");
  const setShowLogin = props.setShowLogin;
  return (
    <div className='login-popup'>
        <form className="login-popup-container">
            <div className="login-popup-title">
                <h2>{currState}</h2>
                <img onClick={()=>setShowLogin(false)} src={assets.cross_icon} alt="" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}


Thank you! It worked, I for sure thought the problem was with the hook.
